# performing operations for the cells in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

I have the following variable:

```
QOS= [100 200 120 300 45 88 90 500 66 180];
```

I have `MPR` that is a `n x n` cell.  It contains some cells that are `2 x 2` double and cells that are `1 x 2` double. I want for the cells that are 2 by 2 double (for example `[2 3 ; 4 5 ]`) to calculate the QOS for each row (ex: `QOS(2)+ QOS(3) = 200+120= 320`), then return the row that has the highest QOS value (ex: `4 5` in this example).

I want for the cells that are 1 by 2 double (for example `[5 6]`) to calculate the QOS for each element (ex: `QOS(5)`= 45), then return the element that has the highest QOS value (ex: `6` in this example).

How could I do such thing??

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way your cell array is structured, the easiest way is to use a `for` loop. I'm sure there are other ways, but for getting something working, let's use a `for` loop.

For each of your cells in your cell array, you would use the matrices to access your `QOS` variable then sum across the columns.  Because your cell array has `1 x 2` matrices, summing over the columns won't give the right result.  As such, in order for our logic to work, you'll need to make sure this is a column vector.  I'll put that logic inside the `for` loop in case.

Once you're done, you would then return the row indices of each cell that corresponds to the maximum sum.  In other words, given your matrix `MPR`, and the variable `out` will store the output, try doing this:

```
QOS = [100 200 120 300 45 88 90 500 66 180]; %// From your post
out = cell(1,numel(MPR)); %// Create output cell array
for idx = 1 : numel(MPR) %// For each cell in MPR...
    matr = QOS(MPR{idx}); %// Access QOS variables defined by MPR cell
    if size(matr,1) == 1 %// Make sure it's a column vector if row vector (1 x 2)
        matr = matr(:);
    end
    [~,loc] = max(sum(matr,2)); %// Sum across all the columns
    out{idx} = matr(loc,:); %// Output row of MPR cell that has max sum
end
```

As an example, supposing `MPR` was your example you have above:

```
MPR{1} = [2 3; 4 5];
MPR{2} = [5 6];
```

Running the above code, we get:

```
>> celldisp(out)

out{1} =

     4     5



out{2} =

     6
```